# Submit data into repeating table in infopath to a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, splistitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to submit data from repeatable table in infopath form to a sharepoint list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37256/how-to-submit-data-from-repeatable-table-in-infopath-form-to-a-sharepoint-list)

I am trying to solve this problem of pulling data into a repeating table, then having the user modify them and submit all the changes.  A repeating table by default does not have the ability to submit data, so I guess it will require some tricks, either CAML or double eval to create a concatenated string which contains all the new data for a given column we are updating.

So far I have checked out:
http://geekswithblogs.net/KunaalKapoor/archive/2012/04/30/how-to-submit-data-from-an-infopath-2010-form-to.aspx

but this looks like a form to create new entries?  Or what am I supposed to do to enter the data into a repeating table then submit changes to the list with no changes if user did not change a field?

also I checked out an answer to a previous question which was still in the "not sufficiently answered" status.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/37259/10213 
I would like to use this trick, but after collecting the information, how are you parsing the character delineated concatenated string and how are you sending it to the correct list?  Any implementation example would be nice.  Would it work for a repeating table which can have any number of rows? (variable in length, depending on how many entries exist, we'll actually have to concatenate fields a different number of times)

Thank you.

Comment: Your mentioned [How to submit data from repeatable table in infopath form to a sharepoint list?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37256/how-to-submit-data-from-repeatable-table-in-infopath-form-to-a-sharepoint-list) has answers and is answered.

Comment: right, which have zero up votes and none selected as a sufficient answer.  I think the one that I linked to would have been sufficient, had he given a concrete example with details on how exactly concatenated strings are delineated, sent to a holding variable, then stored in the correct list.  These tricks are not trivial to do within a sharepoint workflow...

Comment: I suggest you to ask one question a time especially b/c you have here a lot of ambiguous, incorrect or incomprehensible doubts, statements, etc. And this board is not for disputes or discussions but for questions having answers

Comment: Yep, much better to have information in one place. @fa1c0n3r, I would recommend trying to ask PirateEric to explain more by commenting on his answer. You'll need 50 rep to comment or I can help you post the comment.

Comment: sure can you ask for more detail on his solution.  parsing and storing into the original SharePoint list into different arbitrary numbers of rows is that actually doable in sp or just an idea?

Comment: Not sure but users with rep=1 cannot comment. Then, if I want to answer and there is no direct answer considering some incorrect starting statements?  It is impossible to discuss anything (here the traps, tweaks and workarounds of Infopath) in SE sites. I suggest to ask this question in infopathdev.com and I would love to answer it there

Comment: sounds good... I may ask there too.  I guess it is not in common use to use a repeating table for both receiving data and submitting into sharepoint lists.

Comment: This is the point, though it is possible to submit from repeating table and receive to repeating table, I highly doubt that it is reasonable or viable to do both both to and from the same table. So, your individual starting statements in question are arguable