# InfoPath 2010, Sharepoint Liist Form and Custom code

Tags: development, infopath, visual-studio

I'm editing SharePoint 2010 list's Form in InfoPath 2010.
Heard I can edit/add custom code via Visual Studio. Checked all buttons on ribbon but cannot find anything referencing to 'custom code' or developement

I can see 'developer' tab when start InfoPath Designer but it disapears when I open my Form (linked to SP list).

Can you please advise how can I use VS then ?

Answer (score 1):

Client code behind through VSTA (Visual Studio for Applications, and it is not full-pledged Visual Studio... though it is off-topic), which is accessed/created through **Developer** button on ribbon in Infopath Designer is not available for **Sharepoint List Form** type (Compatibility < Form Oprions < Info < File)  of Infopath template

Check also my answer to question ["Custom Code is disabled on my form/(it is a workflow form of a sp list workflow process)/ any workaround?"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/44168)

**Update:**
In "Table 3. Comparing form library and list templates" of MSDN article

- [Building SharePoint Applications with InfoPath 2010 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961896%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (Office 2010/Infopath 2010)

you can find it under entry "Is there support for custom code?"

Note that it is about Sharepoint List Form type of Infopath template. You can bind controls to sharepoint list(s) and engage code-behind in other types of Infopath templates.