# Connecting infopath with the data from the list

Tags: development, infopath, event-receivers

When I creating an InfoPath connected with the list in creator from Microsoft InfoPath Designer the bookmark which called developer is hiding, and I can't editing or writing any of code. How could I connected with the list, and could editing a code in InfoPath? Please help.

Comment: i can't understood what you saying....
can you give more explanation ?

Comment: Infopath blocking my  ModalDialogBoxes wchich are fired from Event Receiver by the code:
`                      properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
                      properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/Add4/MorePercentThenRange.aspx";
                      properties.ErrorMessage = "You cannot save this list item at this time";`

Answer (score 0):

Code-behind is "by-design" [unavailable for Infopath templates of type/compatibility "Sharepoint List Form"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/52683/8319), use other types of forms if you want to code, though coding is bad approach in Infopath forms, aka maintenance horror,  as I cannot imagine what cannot be done codelessly, with rules.