# Validate Infopath form by another SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have 1 Requirement list and 1 Tasks list with InfoPath 2010 forms.

- Tasks list having Lookup column as of Requirement Title field.
- Both lists having Status field.

When user save Requirement (InfoPath form) with `Status=Completed` I want to check whether there is any corresponding tasks exist in tasks list with `Status != Completed`.

if so I want to show a message (or form validation) to the user saying

> "Corresponding Task is open for this requirement.Please complete the open task in order to complete the requirement."

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do it using custom code..

Comment: Thanx for your replied. i have sharepoint list infopath. is it ok? can you please guide me regarding this?

Comment: Is there multiple tasks for single requirement? Ya almost part i have done but I can not check status of task that is completed or not. But i can check that task is exists for that requirement.

Comment: yes there are multiple tasks for single requirement

Answer (score 0):

Concerning comment " you can do it using custom code":

1. [Custom code is impossible for Infopath SharePoint list form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44163/custom-code-is-disabled-on-my-form-it-is-a-workflow-form-of-a-sp-list-workflow);

   The question is quite evasive and ambiguous on whether the Infopath form in question is of type/compatibility Sharepoint List Form...
2. There is no need in coding for this;

What is asked is unclear - what is the type/compatibility of Infopath form and which version of Infopath?
Why do you need message box but not validation rules or [conditional formatting to show and hide a section](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/23813.aspx) ?

Comment: Thax Gennady Vanin, i have updated my question. i dont have any problem if it will be validation rules instead of message box. can u tell me how can i perform that?

Comment: I do not see anything making your question more clear.