# InfoPath not showing latest version after submitting changes

Tags: infopath, form, template

I am working with **InfoPath 2010** programming for **SharePoint 2010**. The template is published on local server drive and Imported using **SharePoint Designer 2010**. I save once and do some revision on the template after that. But after making changes again it still shows the first version.

I try to check in Form Library Settings of site's library web and it reflect with latest update.
I try to check in **SharePoint Designer** under form-lib forms of All-Files. It is OK with latest update.
But when I click Add-document of the form-library `(//the-server/.../ITAsset/Forms/AllItems.aspx)`, it still open old form template.

The strange is when I try to use `//localhost/.../ITAsset/Forms/AllItems.aspx` then it show latest update.

I don't know what make it different. Any explanation or help ?

Comment: Try checking the forms folder in explorer view. Check if it is publishing there by checking the modified date.

Answer (score 1):

I am rather lost what you are doing and why...

If "`the template is published on local server`" , why do you "`try to check in Form Library Settings of site's library web`"?  I could not find that you republish it to your Form Library?

Anyway, you may want to get familiar with [relinking of Infopath XML forms to a newly published template.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44163/custom-code-is-disabled-on-my-form-it-is-a-workflow-form-of-a-sp-list-workflow/44168#44168)

**Update:**
In browser one usually sees the XML data forms generated on the basis of published Infopath XSN form.
You cannot directly see the content of template in browser since XSN template is archive, i.e. a bunch of many files. You can save it locally and export files from it to see its content or open it for design in Infopath Designer.

It is bad idea to check library settings for a template it is linked to. Open XML file for this. See details how to do this by following links in the reference I gave above.

And be careful with yr terminology, your phrases are next to impossible to understand

Comment: I just want to check latest published template that can not show up in the browser with server name. So I try with localhost name, and it show the latest. Checking with Form library setting is to make sure the published template is the latest.

Comment: The real problem is I can not directly see the updated form after re-submit the form template, unless I use localhost. Refreshing IE is not work for form template. I don't know why.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the browser is caching the old template. You can clear the browser cache by doing ctrl + F5 which forces the browser to get the latest files. It sounds like your browser does not cache requests for localhost which some do by design.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well. The form worked fine on my device in SharePoint but it was not loading the "updated" form on a co-workers device.

Did CTRL+F5 on his keyboard and refreshed the library, opened the form, and bingo. New form.

Thanks Ryan Erickson