# submit multiple entries to one list with one infopath form

Tags: infopath

Is there a way to create a single infopath form to submit multiple rows of data to one list (as opposed to making one single entry/filling out one form at a time)?

Comment: I didnot check the option "Manage Multiple List Items with this form" while publishing the form for the first time but now I want to bind my table to repeating table/repeating section and I dont find that option, I saw it only for the first time.. wt to do ?

Comment: Anagha, you should post it as question not as comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use Infopath **Sharepoint List Form** type/compatibility, then you should create it from Infopath Designer 2010  by choosing **Sharepoint List** template (on ribbon File > New ) and at the end of publishing wizard choose:

- **Manage multiple list items with this form**
  This will create repeating fields and add a repeating section to enable usersto edit multiple list items in a single form

[image: Submit multiple entries to one list with one infopath form]

Then it will be possible to drag'n'drop data fields on design surface as repeating controls from under or right-click on my:SharepointListItem_RW in Fields pane and select **Repeating Table** or **Repeating Section with Controls**

[image: right-click on my:SharepointListItem_RW in Fields pane]

It is not available if you create the same by clicking **Customize Form** button on ribbon  (under **Customize List** < **List** tab < List Tools) in browser as well as it is impossible to change such form after it was created with this option unchecked.

The Infopath forms created from a template published to a sharepoint library form can [submit multiple rows into a sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37256/how-to-submit-data-from-repeatable-table-in-infopath-form-to-a-sharepoint-list/44285#44285) as well as there are other (non-straightforward thanks to MS) methods of submitting multiple items to a list or [to multiple lists](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23635/81991.aspx#81991)

Comment: This is a great answer but what if you require additional repeat sections?

Comment: Have you read the last paragraph of my answer? You shouldn't use Infopath form template of type/compatibility Sharepoint List Form for this as it has locked one-to-one binding of its data fields to "its" sharepoint list

Comment: with reference to above ,How to remove one to one binding of data fields from sharepoint list??

Comment: Hi, this is not the discussion board, it is question and answer one. If you have a question, post it as question but not a comment. If it was not answered before. So far, without further explanation, your question does not make any sense to me. If you do not need this feature then do not use this type of Infopath form template or sharepoint list (use library)

Comment: Anagha, The sense of your question is the same as of the question: "How to remove from MS Word TEMPLATE the capability of created on its basis Word documents files to be saved to hard disk?" It has nothing to do with template. You should hack MS Word for this and this would violate licensing terms of using Microsoft products