# Create a SharePoint list form with MULTIPLE repeating tables to submit to a SharePoint List

Tags: 2010, infopath

I've been trying to create a SharePoint List form that has MULTIPLE REPEAT TABLES.  When I try the solution at:  [submit multiple entries to one list with one infopath form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/submit-multiple-entries-to-one-list-with-one-infopath-form) I am not able to add an extra group [node] whereby I can add an additional repeat table.

Does anyone have a solution to this type of business requirement for SharePoint 2010 using InfoPath?

Thank You

Comment: My apologies, forgot to state that I am using InfoPath 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the last paragraph of [my answer you are linking to in your question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/46699/8319)

- "The Infopath forms created from a template published to a **sharepoint LIBRARY** form can [submit multiple rows into a sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37256/how-to-submit-data-from-repeatable-table-in-infopath-form-to-a-sharepoint-list/44285#44285) as well as there are other (non-straightforward thanks to MS) methods of submitting multiple items to a list or [to multiple lists](https://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23635/81991.aspx#81991)"

as well as my answer in the whole dwelling around Infopath form template of type/compatibility **Sharepoint List Form** hinting on its peculiarities [discussed many times before](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/how-to-reconnect-infopath-task-form-to-spd-workflow-after-moving-it-to-the-new-s/41551#41551)?

You shouldn't use Infopath form template of type/compatibility **Sharepoint List Form** for this as it has locked

- locked through **unmodifiable** data connection/source created under the hood when you created such type of form.
  **Sharepoint List Form** is created either by pressing **Customize** button on ribbon of browser or in Sharepoint Designer or choosing File > New > Sharepoint List > then following to fill "the locking" data connection wizard in Infopath Designer 2010 (IPD)
  Please check this inmodifiable data connection/sourcу by  having clicked on ribbon  Data > Data Connections of IPD

data schema to its sharepoint list,  i.e. rigidly bound in one-to-one relationships between Infopath form template data and its sharepoint list

**Update:**
Since you insist on [asking the same again](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54750/create-a-sharepoint-list-form-with-multiple-repeating-tables-to-submit-to-a-shar) I have to ask you:
how do you imagine where how another table, with another schema, would store list items (with a different data schema) in the same sharepoint list (items)?

If you choose to use Sharpoint List Form:

- it is your choice and you should understand what you are doing and what this type of form is by its design for.
  Such type of Infopath form template, **Sharepoint List Form**, is designed **to store items of one and only one sharepoint list** (according according to data schema of one and only one sharepoint list) but not multiple ones
- Sharepoint list is inherently flat, it data schema cannot be hierarchical

You should minimally read on (usage&design) differences between sharepoint list vs. sharepoint library:

- [Comparing SharePoint List and Form Library Forms](https://web.archive.org/web/20151112162455/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/22/comparing-list-and-form-library-forms.aspx)
  The official blog of the Microsoft InfoPath team
- [Chapter 3: Programming SharePoint Lists and Libraries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/dd490727%28v=office.12%29) (MSDN)
- Nik Patel. [InfoPath 2010 and SharePoint 2010 – List Forms vs Library Forms](https://web.archive.org/web/20130603080848/http://nikspatel.wordpress.com:80/2011/12/23/infopath-2010-and-sharepoint-2010-list-forms-vs-library-forms/)
- [Building SharePoint Applications with InfoPath 2010 (Part 1 of 2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff961896%28v=office.14%29#IP14BuildingSPApplicationsPT1_BestPracticesforIPSPApps) (MSDN)
  See there **Table 3. Comparing form library and list templates**

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a list form you have the option of setting it to manage multiple items. Create a new SharePoint list form, use the URL for your list, and select the option to manage multiple items. This only works with Sharepoint 2010.