# Submitting Data via Infopath form to a Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, infopath, sharepoint-list

We have an infopath form that is used to submit data to a sharepoint list.  This form allows a user to enter multiple selections using a people picker and also multiple selections using a repeating table for offices.  We want the user to only have to fill out one form but have that one form create multiple rows in the sharepoint list.  We would need one row for each user in each office.  So, as an example, if a person filled out the form one time and it had 3 users and 3 offices, this would create 9 entries as follows:
ID #1 - User A / Office A
ID #2 - User A / Office B
ID #3 - User A / Office C
ID #4 - User B / Office A
ID #5 - User B / Office B
ID #6 - User B / Office C
ID #7 - User C / Office A
ID #8 - User C / Office B
ID #9 - User C / Office C

I cannot figure out how to build a workflow that would automatically kick off each time a form is submitted to do this.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we could achieve this using workflow and InfoPath.

I suggest you insert a repeating section to include the person and choice field.

Then insert multiple items in one form manually.

[image]

More information for your reference:

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-repeating-section-2b72cf6b-3a16-4e60-ba60-56fbfcadb5a6#:~:text=%2BI%2C%20C.-,Under%20Insert%20controls%2C%20click%20Repeating%20Section.,fields%20in%20the%20data%20source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-repeating-section-2b72cf6b-3a16-4e60-ba60-56fbfcadb5a6#:%7E:text=%2BI%2C%20C.-,Under%20Insert%20controls%2C%20click%20Repeating%20Section.,fields%20in%20the%20data%20source).

[submit multiple entries to one list with one infopath form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/submit-multiple-entries-to-one-list-with-one-infopath-form)