# How To Autosave a Form Based on a Infopath-based Content Type?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, content-type

Salvete! I have followed [this guide](http://blogs.interfacett.com/using-infopath-2010-to-create-a-custom-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010) and created a site-content-type using infopath (very tedious if you have lots of fields).

Now, how can I make it so folks can fill out my new form?

Then I followed [this guide](http://blogs.interfacett.com/creating-a-custom-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010-by-spike-xavier), and created a document library in which to save the forms once they are filled out.  This works, but, not like other lists.  First, I get no "okay" button, and then, when I push the "save" button, I get a "Save As" box, saying "You can only save this file to the current site." with a place for a filename.  This will confuse the tar out of my users!

Surely there is a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are after a web enabled form using InfoPath 2010 and SP 2010

- In InfoPath ensure the Tool bar is enabled (under > File > Form Options > Web Browser)
- Under File > Submit Options > you might have to configure the submit action to submit to library or list
- Other option is you can add a button to the form. Set the action to "Rule" and add a rule that will submit the data using the Main data connection.
- You can also specify a rule to create a custom file name so the user does not get prompted for a file name http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/06/20/auto-generating-filenames-for-infopath-forms/

Happy SharePointing :)

Comment: Ah! You mean to say that if I autogenerate a filename that it won't prompt the user to save?  I want to avoid the prompt altogether.

Comment: Correct, so if the user for instance clicks on the Save button, the file name will be auto generated and the user will not be prompted. So you will apply your business logic using "rules" for the button.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to:

- [Under File > Submit Options > you might have to configure the submit action to submit to library or list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/49076/8319)

It is impossible OOTB (Out of the Box, without hacking, using 3d-party tools, etc.) to submit or publish a regular Infopath template form to a sharepoint list.

It is possible OOTB (without hacking source files) to create an Infopath Form of type/compatibility "Sharepoint List Form" which can be created in particular ways only (I know only three of them):

- clicking a violet "Customize From" button on ribbon in browser (having navigated to a sharepoint list)
- using "Sharepoin List" button > **Design Form** in Infopath Designer 2010 (File > New on ribbon)
- in Sharepoint Designer 2010, navigate to sharepoint list and press Design Forms in Infopath > Item on ribbon

See [my answer to question "Cannot edit form in InfoPath when list was created in Visual Studio"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49100/cannot-edit-form-in-infopath-when-list-was-created-in-visual-studio/49105#49105) on this

Though there are some workarounds how to submit to sharepoint lists from regular Infopath forms. See:

- my answer to question ["How to submit data from repeatable table in infopath form to a sharepoint list?"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/44285/8319)
- etc.

I stop here since I am diverting from original question.

Comment: Okay, that is a straight answer - that it isn't possible to publish a regular infopath form to a sp list.  However, what I am asking is for a way to make my infopath form *act* like a Sharepoint list.  I don't want to use a sharepoint list - because I want a content-type instead.  I need to be able to make changes that will go out to every instance of the form - hence the content type.

Comment: The straight answer was that it was impossible OOTB (by tools, UI provided by Microsoft though there are 3d-party tools for this, hacking, workarounds, etc.). I believe I addressed your other questions in your other threads

Comment: Each question I asked is different.  They are certainly related, but require different answers; hence, multiple questions about the same topic.  In this question, I am not asking how to publish the form TO a sharepoint list; I am asking how to avoid prompting the user to save the file.

Comment: I did not answer your question. I replied to incorrect statement of another answer. But you should have posted one question per post

Comment: My apologies. You are right; my question isn't that clear.  However, I think MicrosoftDevX has the answer, as I have tried that and it does, indeed, allow the user to fill out the infopath form.

Comment: Could you please give a reference to that MicrosoftDevX answer/solution?

Comment: Uh, it is the other answer on this page...