# Sharepoint 2013 List/Form with Repeating and Non Repeating sections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, infopath, list-form

Can someone point me to how to go about creating a sharepoint list form with a repeating and non repeating section?

For example, a form that basically submits a team's information to a sharepoint list. we have a list with 6 fields and we want to be able to add indefinite number of Members for the form. So that when we save if you added 6 members, it would creat 6 rows of records. However we don't want to have to type in Team info everytime. (The advanced options allows me to manage multiple list items with the form but it makes the [whole form repeatable](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37256/how-to-submit-data-from-repeatable-table-in-infopath-form-to-a-sharepoint-list)). not just sections. I've also looked into creating a sharepoint form library with a repeating table but since it looks like infopath forms don't directly saves into a sharepoint list in this option, I was hoping someone has a better idea or if they have done this solution before. Most of the community online seems to reference a [solution](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-submit-items-rows-repeating-table-infopath-sharepoint-list.htm) that's from 2007. I was hoping for a more updated solution now that we are using sharepoint 2013. Unfortunately, they would all be contained in one list so that the business users can query and sort them.

Fields:

- Team Name
- Team Color
- Team Number
- Member Name
- Member age
- Member weight

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to split the data into two lists and display them on two forms. One list to hold teams and another list to hold the members. The members list will need a Team field that is a lookup to the Team list.

You have a form for creating Teams where they enter all the team info like Name, Color and Number. Then you have another form for entering members where all they need to fill in is the Team lookup field.

Although it is possible to display the Members form as a repeating section on the Team form I don't think InfoPath supports [creating/editing rows in repeating sections](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/ec039b4e-3ba0-417e-a123-cfc7cb1408ee) OOTB.

Comment: unfortunately, we need all the info in one list so that business can query it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem solved by creating a blank InfoPath form, inserting repeating and non-repeating fields and then publishing to list. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution from here => http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-repeating-rows/overview/. There is trial time you can check whether it fulfills your requirement or not.